# Finding a value based on the roots of an equation

Tags: roots

So I saw this question recently:

> Known $a^2+b^2+6a-12b+45=0$. Find $\dfrac{b-a}{b+a}$.

I tried to factorize it but I don't really know how. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because just like [every other question of yours](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/338209/blastzit?tab=questions), you show no effort whatsoever in attempting to answer it on your own. Asking 'Can anyone help me with it?' is simply not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ (a+3)^2 + (b-6)^2 = 0 $$
only at $a=-3, b=6$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT :

$$(a^2+6a+9)-9+(b^2-12b+36)-36+45=0$$